# Set connection friendly name in Go amqp client

Tags: go, amqp

I am using the http://github.com/streadway/amqp package in my application in order to handle connections to a remote RabbitMQ server. Everything is ok and works fine, but I have a question.

The current name for a connection is "ip:port", so when there are multiple connections from the same IP+port, they become hardly distinguishable. It would be great if you can specify a name for each connection.

Is there any way to set a distinct friendly name for each connection?

Comment: add the domain name followed by address in your `/etc/hosts` file, if you are using *nix, windows also have something similar.

Comment: When you have a bunch of connections from the same ip ? What about it ? I have some subsystem in one server. @nilsocket

Comment: It doesn't matter, all dns queries goes through os, os first looks into the file, if not available, queries dns server. I'm not sure what you are asking exactly, some code example would help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RabbitMQ 3.6.5 added the facility for the connecting client to report a *friendly name* string value to identify a connection for management purposes. This is strictly an identifier and, as it is client-reported, it cannot be relied upon for anything other than weak identification of connections. The [release notes](https://rabbitmq.docs.pivotal.io/36/relnotes/release-notes-rabbitmq3.6.5.html) state:

> Clients now can provide a human-readable connection name that will be displayed in the management UI... In order to use this feature, set the `connection_name` key in client properties. Note that this name doesn’t have to be unique and cannot be used as a connection identifier, for example, in HTTP API requests.

---

## Solution

Provided you are using a sufficiently new version of RabbitMQ, you can set this parameter when making connections using `streadway/amqp` by passing an instance of `amqp.Config` when making the initial connection. The `Properties` field allows custom properties of the connection to be specified.

The example program below opens a connection using the AMQP URL provided in the environment variable `AMQP_URL`, identified using the connection name passed as the first command line argument to the invocation.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

func main() {
    amqpUrl := os.Getenv("AMQP_URL")

    cfg := amqp.Config{
        Properties: amqp.Table{
            "connection_name": os.Args[1],
        },
    }

    conn, err := amqp.DialConfig(amqpUrl, cfg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    <-(chan struct{})(nil)
}
```

Starting multiple instances to connect to a local RabbitMQ instance using the following command line:

```golang
AMQP_URL=amqp://admin:password@localhost:5672 go run ./main.go connX
```

where a numeral is substituted for `X` yields the following output in the "Connections" page of the RabbitMQ Management web UI:

[image: RabbitMQ connections showing friendly names conn1, conn2 and conn3.]

and the individual connection detail pages shows the value under the "Client-provided name" detail value:

[image: Client-provided name shows the connection name on the connection detail page in the management UI.]