# How to set connection friendly name RabbitMQ --Python

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I am playing around with RabbitMq and I have a question. I have many parallel nodes running and are connected on rabbitmq-server. The thing is that in conncetions are stated like `ip:port` Also under `ip:port` there is a `?`. Is there a way to set up a friendly name for python 3.6?

[image]

P.S I have tried something like this without success

```
                    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(
                        host='localhost',
                        virtual_host='/',
                        client_properties={
                            'connection_name': 'random name',
                        },
                    )
                    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
```

P.S Also i found a related question about golang tho. Here [Set connection friendly name in Go amqp client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568636/how-to-set-connection-friendly-name)

Versions

```
pika = '1.1.0'
RabbitMq = '3.8.0'
Erlang = '22.1.1'
Python = ' 3.6.8'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you ask a question, you *must* provide versions of all software used - Pika library version, RabbitMQ, Erlang, operating system, and Python (3.6.???)

Comment: Hello Sorry for that. 
pika = "==1.0.1"
RabbitMq = '3.8.0'
Erlang = '22.1.1'
Python = ' 3.6.8'

Answer (score 4):

[This code](https://gist.github.com/lukebakken/b0a6852a7030303370f2259f687c0662) sets the connection name as you can see here:

[image]

```py
import functools
import logging
import pika

LOG_FORMAT = ('%(levelname) -10s %(asctime)s %(name) -30s %(funcName) '
              '-35s %(lineno) -5d: %(message)s')
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=LOG_FORMAT)


def on_message(chan, method_frame, _header_frame, body, userdata=None):
    """Called when a message is received. Log message and ack it."""
    LOGGER.info('Userdata: %s Message body: %s', userdata, body)
    chan.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method_frame.delivery_tag)


def main():
    """Main method."""
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('guest', 'guest')
    props = { 'connection_name' : 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/58275505/1466825' }
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost', credentials=credentials, client_properties=props)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)

    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.exchange_declare(
        exchange='test_exchange',
        exchange_type='direct',
        passive=False,
        durable=True,
        auto_delete=False)
    channel.queue_declare(queue='standard', auto_delete=True)
    channel.queue_bind(
        queue='standard', exchange='test_exchange', routing_key='standard_key')
    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)

    on_message_callback = functools.partial(
        on_message, userdata='on_message_userdata')
    channel.basic_consume('standard', on_message_callback)

    try:
        channel.start_consuming()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        channel.stop_consuming()

    connection.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your time. I tried that with no luck. Code is running ok but it keeps showing ? under ip::port

Comment: I know it works as I just tried it. Please run the code I provided using Pika **1.1.0** and share the output from your environment. It will log at the DEBUG level.

Comment: I just updated to pika 1.1.0. still no luck. I know that your is working for sure. i just can not find my silly mistake!

Comment: When i copy paste your code it works. When i try to replicate that on mine i get ```?``` as name

Comment: You're being very unclear. When you say "copy paste your code" do you run my _entire_ code sample or just copy the part that creates the connection? This all would be _much easier_ if you would just share your code that isn't working.

Comment: Sorry again for being unclear. If you have time check that https://codeshare.io/5Qvqbe

Comment: That code is **very inefficient**, but it should work. You should NOT create a new connection per message! What is happening is that your connections are being created and closed so fast there is no time for the connection name to update in the management web site. I have updated your code.

Comment: @LukeBakken Could you paste a sample code in the text of the answer? The link no longer works

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lukebakken/b0a6852a7030303370f2259f687c0662

Comment: This can also be set via the connection URL, here's what it would look like `"amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2F?client_properties={'connection_name':'my-custom-name'}"`.